# Playing local mp4 file in electron

Tags: macos, html5-video, electron

I am trying to develop a small application in which I first capture screen via `aperture` package and then try to show it in the screen using `video` tag.

I capture screen via:

```
import apertureConstructor from 'aperture';
const aperture = apertureConstructor();

const options = {
  fps: 30
};

(async () => {
  await aperture.startRecording(options);
  setTimeout(async () => {
    this.captureUrl = await aperture.stopRecording();
  }, 3000)
})();
```

Please ignore the mess. `Aperture` package writes captured video to disk and eventually, I have the path to this file in `captureUrl`. It is something like this:

`/var/folders/29/08gshk3n4mlbbcjnm1m5xyy40000gp/T/tmp-79999m0uOszQK0zaC.mp4`

I can verify that this file exists and plays just fine, if I type: `file:///var/folders/29/08gshk3n4mlbbcjnm1m5xyy40000gp/T/tmp-79999m0uOszQK0zaC.mp4` to Google Chrome address bar.

So I try to use this address as the source of my `video` tag like this:

```
 <video control autoplay>
   <source src="/var/folders/29/08gshk3n4mlbbcjnm1m5xyy40000gp/T/tmp-8004145a2o4gugbVV.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Which complains that file is not there (404):

```
GET http://localhost:9080/var/folders/29/08gshk3n4mlbbcjnm1m5xyy40000gp/T/tmp-8004145a2o4gugbVV.mp4 404 (Not Found)
```

And yes, it indeed tries to go to `localhost:9080` because in this case it is my development server host and there is no such a file.

So I decide to add `file://`...

```
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="file:///var/folders/29/08gshk3n4mlbbcjnm1m5xyy40000gp/T/tmp-8004145a2o4gugbVV.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This time it says:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///var/folders/29/08gshk3n4mlbbcjnm1m5xyy40000gp/T/tmp-80041e3SlBZUNphLM.mp4
```

:/

I wonder if I missed something that makes "file://" secure or something else.

I also thought about reading the whole file via "fs" and base64'ing it providing video as `data:` but as this video file might be large, I feel like I shouldn't go that way.

As I am new to `electron` I hope I miss something basic. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though I do not like encouraging this, I'd suggest you disable web security preference within BrowserWindow for the sake of resolution. Also, there is an [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5107) related to this topic.

Comment: I'm converting a webapp that involves video to an Electron app, and I don't understand the relevance of web security preferences to a desktop (Electron) app. The user installed the app and therefore trusts it.  Web security pertains to the web and running code from sources you can't trust.

Answer (score 11):

Since there is already an accepted answer, I will just tell you how I solved this for people that may encounter the same problem.

At this time there is a way to do this by using [protocol](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol), even if you specify

```js
webPreferences: {
  webSecurity: true,
}
```

Normally to display an image or play a video from a file you would do

```html
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="file:///path-to-video.mp4">
</video>
```

but this won't work with webpack because webpack spawns a server and by default everyhing that starts with `file://` will not be loaded due to security reasons. If the electron is loaded with a `file://index.html` then it may work but the [protocol](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol) way is pretty cool and you can secure your resources.

To overcome your issue you can do something like the following:

```js
const { protocol } = require('electron');

function fileHandler(req, callback){
  let requestedPath = req.url
  // Write some code to resolve path, calculate absolute path etc
  let check = // Write some code here to check if you should return the file to renderer process

  if (!check){
    callback({
      // -6 is FILE_NOT_FOUND
      // https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:net/base/net_error_list.h
      error: -6 
    });
    return;
  }

  callback({
    path: requestedPath
  });
}

// Then in electron main.js

app.on("ready", () => {
  
  protocol.registerFileProtocol(
    'your-custom-protocol',
    fileHandler,
  );

  // Create some window you can even use webPreferences: true
});
```

Then you can use it in your html code like this

```html
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="your-custom-protocol:///path-to-video.mp4">
</video>
```

By doing this you can be sure that your app is secure and that it is not requesting random files from the file system and it also works with webpack really well.

For more about this there is a github repo to showcase secure patterns in electron.
Take a look at it [here](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template)

Comment: this saved my hours
works as expected

Comment: It's 2023 and electron has marked `protocol.registerFileProtocol` as deprecated :( and I can't find any alternative. Please help!

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into the same issue. You can set (in main process):

```
webPreferences: {
  webSecurity: false
}
```

This will allow you to load `file://` urls from a user's HDD. However, this is really bad practice as it opens up security.

The accepted way would be to:

```
webPreferences: {
  webSecurity: true
}
```

And, then from your main process create a web server that serves up the files you want.

In your main process:

```
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const expressApp = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const router = express.Router()
```

Then do the following code:

```
expressApp.use(cors())

router.get('/file/:name', function (req, res) {
  let filename = req.params.name
  res.sendFile(filename)
})

expressApp.use('/', router)

http.createServer(expressApp).listen(8000)
```

Now, in your js/html in the renderer code, you can set `src` in the video tag to be:

```
'http://localhost:8000/file/' + filename
```

Comment: I would consider this safer if we didn't just make a server which would literally serve any file on the filesystem which any client might ask for...